# Keras 1D CNN always predicts the same result even if accuracy is high on training set

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

The validation accuracy of my 1D CNN is stuck on 0.5 and that's because I'm always getting the same prediction out of a balanced data set. At the same time my training accuracy keeps increasing and the loss decreasing as intended.

Strangely, if I do `model.evaluate()` on my training set (that has close to 1 accuracy in the last epoch), the accuracy will also be 0.5. How can the accuracy here differ so much from the training accuracy of the last epoch? I've also tried with a batch size of 1 for both training and evaluating and the problem persists.

Well, I've been searching for different solutions for quite some time but still no luck. Possible problems I've already looked into:

1. My data set is properly balanced and shuffled;
2. My labels are correct;
3. Tried adding fully connected layers;
4. Tried adding/removing dropout from the fully connected layers;
5. Tried the same architecture, but with the last layer with 1 neuron and sigmoid activation;
6. Tried changing the learning rates (went down to 0.0001 but still the same problem).

---

**Here's my code:**

```
import pathlib
import numpy as np
import ipynb.fs.defs.preprocessDataset as preprocessDataset
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

main_folder = pathlib.Path.cwd().parent
datasetsFolder=f'{main_folder}\\datasets'
trainDataset = preprocessDataset.loadDataset('DatasetTime_Sg12p5_Ov75_Train',datasetsFolder)
testDataset = preprocessDataset.loadDataset('DatasetTime_Sg12p5_Ov75_Test',datasetsFolder)

X_train,Y_train,Names_train=trainDataset[0],trainDataset[1],trainDataset[2]
X_test,Y_test,Names_test=testDataset[0],testDataset[1],testDataset[2]

model = Sequential()

model.add(Input(shape=X_train.shape[1:]))

model.add(Conv1D(16, 61, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2, padding="valid"))

model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2, padding="valid"))

model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2, padding="valid"))

model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2, padding="valid"))

model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, strides=1, padding="same"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(200))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.01)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=10,shuffle=False,validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

model.evaluate(X_train,Y_train)
```

---

**Here's model.fit():**

```
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=10,shuffle=False,validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

Epoch 1/10
914/914 [==============================] - 277s 300ms/step - loss: 0.6405 - accuracy: 0.6543 - val_loss: 7.9835 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/10
914/914 [==============================] - 270s 295ms/step - loss: 0.3997 - accuracy: 0.8204 - val_loss: 19.8981 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/10
914/914 [==============================] - 273s 298ms/step - loss: 0.2976 - accuracy: 0.8730 - val_loss: 1.9558 - val_accuracy: 0.5002
Epoch 4/10
914/914 [==============================] - 278s 304ms/step - loss: 0.2897 - accuracy: 0.8776 - val_loss: 20.2678 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 5/10
914/914 [==============================] - 277s 303ms/step - loss: 0.2459 - accuracy: 0.8991 - val_loss: 5.4945 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 6/10
914/914 [==============================] - 268s 294ms/step - loss: 0.2008 - accuracy: 0.9181 - val_loss: 32.4579 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 7/10
914/914 [==============================] - 271s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1695 - accuracy: 0.9317 - val_loss: 14.9538 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 8/10
914/914 [==============================] - 276s 302ms/step - loss: 0.1423 - accuracy: 0.9452 - val_loss: 1.4420 - val_accuracy: 0.4988
Epoch 9/10
914/914 [==============================] - 266s 291ms/step - loss: 0.1261 - accuracy: 0.9497 - val_loss: 4.3830 - val_accuracy: 0.5005
Epoch 10/10
914/914 [==============================] - 272s 297ms/step - loss: 0.1142 - accuracy: 0.9548 - val_loss: 1.6054 - val_accuracy: 0.5009
```

**Here's model.evaluate():**

```
model.evaluate(X_train,Y_train)

914/914 [==============================] - 35s 37ms/step - loss: 1.7588 - accuracy: 0.5009
```

**Here's model.summary():**

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 4096, 16)          992       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 4096, 16)          64        
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 4096, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 2048, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 2048, 32)          1568      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 2048, 32)          128       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 2048, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 1024, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 1024, 64)          6208      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 1024, 64)          256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 1024, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 512, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 512, 64)           12352     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 512, 64)           256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 512, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling1 (None, 256, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_4 (Conv1D)            (None, 256, 64)           12352     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 256, 64)           256       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 256, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 16384)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 16384)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 200)               3277000   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 200)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 402       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 2)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 3,311,834
Trainable params: 3,311,354
Non-trainable params: 480
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Can you put some code snippet on how you are executing these statements? Without knowing what data is used, can't say much about low validation accuracy. Strange to see model.evaluate performing so bad over training dataset. Check if you are changing training dataset before calling model.evaluate

Comment: The data I'm using is the velocity response over time from several points in a simulation. Plottting the data it is clear the differences, and I've seen 1D CNNs being applied in a case like this, that's why this results confuse me. Anyhow, even if the neural network was performing poorly, or the data was too hard to learn on, like you pointed out, I can't explain model.evaluate performing so bad on the training set, after the accuracy recorded on the last epoch. The predictions are always 1 of the classes with a huge confidence. I added the code to the post, I hope I'm doing a silly mistake.

Comment: What are you trying to model? Can you explain the output and the output layer?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal So I have a simulation with some non-linearities (defects) in some areas. Since I know which are the points with this non-linearities I have the labels for defect/non-defect points. Then, for every point I have it's response over time, and that's my input for the CNN. Defected points show a higher response. My output layer is a softmax layer to classify defect/non-defect (also tried with sigmoid but the issue persists).

Comment: What are the class proportions?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal 50/50. And that's why the accuracy is 0.5, it is always predicting the same class.

Comment: Could you show what y_train looks like? is it a 1D array or 2D?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal It's a 2D numpy array, Y_train shape: (29232, 2). 
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 ...
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem was implementing Batch Renormalization: `BatchNormalization(renorm=True)`. In addition normalizing the inputs helped a lot improving the overall performance of the neural network.

Answer (score 0):

> ... also tried with sigmoid but the issue persists ...

You don't want to be *"trying"* out activation functions or loss functions for a well-defined problem statement. It seems you are mixing up a single-label multi-class and a multi-label multi-class architecture.

Your output is a 2 class multi-class output with `softmax` activation which is great, but you use `binary_crossentropy` which would only make sense when used in a multi-class setting for multi-label problems.

You would want to use `categorical_crossentropy` instead. Furthermore, I would have suggested `focal loss` if there was class imbalance but it seems you have a 50,50 class proportion, so that's not necessary.

Remember, `accuracy` is decided based on which loss is being used! Check the different classes [here](https://keras.io/api/metrics/accuracy_metrics/). When you use `binary_crossentropy` the accuracy used is `binaryaccuracy` while with `categorical_crossentropy`, it uses `categoricalaccuracy`

Check this chart for details on what to use in what type of problem statement.

[image]

---

Other than that, there is a bottleneck in your network at `flatten()` and `Dense()`. The number of trainable parameters is quite high relative to other layers. I would advise using another CNN layer to bring the number of filters to say 128 and the size of sequence even smaller. And reduce the number of neurons for that Dense layer as well.

> 98.9% (3,277,000/3,311,354) of all of your trainable parameters reside between the `Flatten` and `Dense` layer! Not a great architectural choice!

Outside the above points, the model results are totally dependent on your data itself. I wouldn't be able to help more without knowledge of the data.